# Test RabbitTemplate#convertAndSend as lambda with Mockito & JUnit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, rabbitmq, mockito

I am trying to test the [RabbitTemplate#convertAndSend](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#convertAndSend-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-org.springframework.amqp.core.MessagePostProcessor-) method that is written as a lambda, like so:

```
// other stuff omitted for brevity

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(myQueue, jsonString, message -> {
        message.getMessageProperties().setPriority(priority);
        return message;
        });

// other stuff omitted for brevity
```

The test case I am trying to do is one where an `ArgumentCaptor` is being used in order to verify that the method is called with correct parameters.

```
@Test
public void givenMyNotification_whenElementIsSent_thenSetPriorityAndSendValidParameters() {

final ArgumentCaptor<String> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
final int expectedPriority = 5;
final Notification expected = TestUtils.getNotification();

testClass.handleNotification(expected);

verify(rabbitTemplate).convertAndSend(captor.capture(), captor.capture(),
    ArgumentMatchers.eq(MessagePostProcessor.class));

// assertThat...
));

}
```

The test fails at the verify step because the arguments are different.

```
Wanted:
<Capturing argument>,
<Capturing argument>,
interface org.springframework.amqp.core.MessagePostProcessor

Actual invocation:
"myQueue",
"myJson",
com.example.notification.service.NotificationService$$Lambda$5/73698537@5bda80bf
```

I have tried several other Matchers from mockito and hamcrest but to no avail.

So, my questions are:

1. How does one test this kind of a thing?
2. Is this even a good practice or are there other/better ways to test rabbit template sending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost get it all right, except for the last matcher `ArgumentMatchers.eq(MessagePostProcessor.class)`.

You actually ask **Mockito** to match for **equatility** to the class of the parameter.
You should rather match against:

- the type of the parameter using `ArgumentMatchers.any(MessagePostProcessor.class)`
- or an actual value `ArgumentMatchers.eq(expectedMessageProcessor)` if you happen to have it
- or an argument captor if you do need to check the value of the parameter

In this particular case however, if you use the first option, you may run into a compiler issue, as `RabbitTemplate` class has two similar methods:

- convertAndSend(String, String, Object)
- convertAndSend(String, Object, MessagePostProcessor)

To solve this you can force the type of the second parameter to object like this :

```
Mockito.verify(rabbitTemplate).convertAndSend(captor.capture(), (Object) captor.capture(),
            Mockito.any(MessagePostProcessor.class));
```

Or better, have two different `ArgumentCaptor`s for two different parameters:

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> routingKeyCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
ArgumentCaptor<Object> messageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);

...

verify(rabbitTemplate).convertAndSend(routingKeyCaptor.capture(), messageCaptor.capture(), any(MessagePostProcessor.class));
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on what you're *really* trying to test and what business value it adds.

1. Do you want to test the `RabbitTemplate` itself? The Spring repo has tests for this, but IMHO you shouldn't need to do this.
2. Are you testing a Spring `Service` and you have to verify that a message was sent?
3. Do you want to make sure the message will reach its destination?

For (1) there are some examples of exactly the type of tests you're writing in the `Spring Framework` [here in their unit tests for the `RabbitTemplate`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplateTests.java).

For example, verifying that the underlying `ConnectionFactory` actually [created a channel](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplateTests.java#L139):

```
    txTemplate.execute(status -> {
        template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar");
        return null;
    });
    txTemplate.execute(status -> {
        template.convertAndSend("baz", "qux");
        return null;
    });
    verify(mockConnectionFactory, Mockito.times(1)).newConnection(any(ExecutorService.class), anyString());
    // ensure we used the same channel
    verify(mockConnection, times(1)).createChannel();
```

For (2) above, you don't need to use argument captors, etc. You can inject a mock `RabbitTemplate` into the service and I personally like to either test against the argument I called the method with or to use `Mockito#any`, etc.

FYI, in terms of assertions, I'd also take a look at [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/), it has a nice stamp of approval from Spring, and the fluent API for it (esp. with intellisense) makes it very easy to use.

For (3), I'd highly recommend https://www.testcontainers.org/ (if you're using docker), and I haven't checked it out but there may be a JUnit `@Rule` for creating a RabbitMQ broker (I'll have to check on this). I've done something like that for `ActiveMQ Artemis` which very quickly starts up a broker for you and you can consume the messages queued to it.

Comment: As these are just unit tests, I definitely don't want to use test containers. And no, I am not testing the `RabbitTemplate`, the spring developers have done that already. I want to test if the message is being sent with the expected arguments so `any()` is not an option.